# Psensor only shows HDD and CPU usage, not temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature, psensor

Okay I have psensor installed, I installed lm-sensor and some other related packages, I ran sensors-detect and didn't come up with anything. It is only showing my HDDs, and my CPU *usage* not temperatures or anything like that.

Proc:

```
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 4
model name  : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 920 Processor
```

Motherboard:

```
Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: GA-MA78GM-US2H
```

I'm pretty new to temperature sensors in linux, let alone fan sensors (which I would like too). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AMD 10h k10temp kernel doc](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/hwmon/k10temp;h=90956b6180254915e9ff17bb968729c20e043369;hb=HEAD)

Is the k10temp module loaded? It's part of the standard ubuntu kernel.

```
ubuntu-precise$ modinfo k10temp
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/k10temp.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Clemens Ladisch 
description:    AMD Family 10h+ CPU core temperature monitor
srcversion:     7C939FE331D037CED8E383B
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001603sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001703sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001303sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001203sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force:force loading on processors with erratum 319 (bool)
```

Comment: /etc/modules only shows ip, rtc and it87 (last one added by lm-sensors)

Comment: I added this to my modules list, rebooted, and I seem to have fan and CPU temp sensors now. Although I have 3 sensors now, I am not sure which one is CPU?

Comment: Well on my i5... 

ls /sys/bus/platform/drivers/coretemp/coretemp.0
driver  modalias  power      temp2_crit        temp2_input  temp2_max   temp4_crit_alarm  temp4_label  uevent
hwmon   name      subsystem  temp2_crit_alarm  temp2_label  temp4_crit  temp4_input       temp4_max

So it looks like it uses the hwmon interface. The hardware sensors applet works for me, just had to enter the prefs and enable the specific sensors. There's just so many of them. BTW it helps to accept answers that work to encourage other contributors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:
[PSensors don't detect all sensors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155811/psensors-dont-detect-all-sensors)

Another webpage, more detailed:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-sensors-information/

The steps you should follow are:

1. install `lm-sensors` and `psensor`
2. run `sudo sensors-detect`
3. run `psensor`, then in the menus:

   - in /preferences/startup, click the launch at startup.
   - in /sensor-preferences, edit the labels to match your system. you cannot delete a sensor, but you can choose not to display it.