# PSensors don't detect all sensors

Tags: 10.04, sensors

On windows I can see my CPU sensor, but in Ubuntu, using PSensor, I can't see CPU sensor. It detects GPU sensor (which I don't have) and it detects CPU usage. Is there any other tool which can detect my CPU temperature sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo sensors-detect` on terminal and answer the questions with yes (mostly).
 Now run this command: `sudo service module-init-tools restart`  
 Now check the temperatures using `sensors -s` command on terminal. If it works.. restart psensors. If not, follow this page and see if it helps. Link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933020

You might also want to see this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

Comment: it's not working, I tried both of your methods. After I answer YES to all questions, I run sensors -s and then it says No sensors detected. Then I followed instructions on that link and when I type make, it says there is no makefile (something like that).

Comment: actually it says: No rule to make target

Comment: @Alen You need to install lm-sensors first which is what detects the temperatures. psensor is just a frontend for lm-sensors. Install it by typing sudo apt-get install lm-sensors.. After that follow the instructions from the answer I posted above.

Comment: they are already installed

Comment: @Alen If you didn't try the last link that I added in the above answer, Try and see if it helps! If it doesn't, I'd not be able to help on this question further..

Comment: second link helped me but my problem is not fully solved. Now I can see HDD temperature, but my CPU temperature show 127° C which is not correct, and that value is constant.

Answer (score 1):

As already said by drake01, Psensor is 'just' a GUI front-end on top of few libraries providing temperature information. 
For mother-board it uses lm-sensors, basically you need to install it (the package is lm-sensors), then run 'sensors-detect' as root. You will find more information at [lm-sensors FAQ](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter2) or [Psensor installation](http://wpitchoune.net/blog/psensor/). 
If the command 'sensors' displays some temperature sensors but not Psensor, feel free to report a bug to me (jeanfi@gmail.com). If 'sensors' reports no temperature sensors, your hardware is not supported or you should ask the lm-sensors team.

There are many other tools similar to Psensor, for example Xsensors or the excellent indicator-sensors from Alex Murray. Anyway, there are all based on lm-sensors, so the first step is to have lm-sensors running correctly.